# Why java with -jar ignores -classpath?

Tags: java, javac

I have read in docs, especially here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest
that -classpath is ignored when java is called with -jar option.
In this case, resources are read from manifest file.
Maybe I misunderstanding and the way to set paths from out resource is exist when call java -jar?
If not why so?

Comment: If the Russian in your question is just a translation of your above question, please remove it.  Only English questions are allowed on Stack Overflow.  The text is just noise otherwise.

Comment: FYI there is a [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 3):

This is just how the `java` programs was coded to behave.

What's important is that you can still use a JAR **and** specify the class path on the command line. This requires that you make the jar itself part of the class path, and then specify the class, such as:

```
java -cp javafile.jar fully.qualified.ClassName
```

Java will run the `fully.qualified.ClassName` main class, which it will find on the class path (in which the jar file is included).

Comment: Thank for hint (but it doesnt works, seems I do smth wrong).
I try to model the next situation: I have jar with code which depends on some Some.class. (May be this Some.class very common, and I dont want to include it in my jar). I want to execute it with explicit invoke of dependencies.

Comment: Can you share your setup (the main class, the layout of the jar containing it, as well as your current `java` command)?

Comment: `java -cp "HelloSimple.jar:." HelloWorldSimple`

Where HelloSimple.jar contains the only HelloWorldSimple.class
and current directory contains dependency, which used in code

`Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldSimple`

Comment: And what error is it showing? Main class-related, or failing to load classes?

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldSimple`

Comment: Then it can only be the classpath you specified: 1. Are you on Linux? if you're on windows, then use `;` instead of `:`. 2. Is `HelloWorldSimple` not in a package? If it is under a package, you must use a fully qualified class name, not just the simple name.

Comment: I am on linux. HelloWorldSimple is not in a package. (I have done it willfully)